# Displaying the checkbox in angular2

Tags: angular2-forms

I am working on a checkbox display .In my form I am selecting the check box and saving it and in the display of the form I am not able to see it. How to rectify it

Enclosing the screenshot and code

selected checkbox

[image]

To be displayed(the check box shd be displayed below experience

[image]

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label *ngIf="isEdit" for="checkbox1">
    <label *ngIf="!isEdit" for="hf-checkbox1">{{modelr.College_Grad}}</label>
    <input id="checkbox1"  *ngIf="isEdit" name="checkbox1" type="checkbox" 
    value="option1" [value]="modelr.College_Grad"
   (input)="modelr.College_Grad = $event.target.value" > 
         Iam college grad
       </label>
    </div>
```

Comment: Have you checked console ?

Comment: yes  i hav done it

Comment: What you are getting? You need to put some more details regarding your issue. If possible create plunkr of it